# Remove everything after the final "/" in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some private Vimeo Pro urls, where they add what looks like a UUID to the end to enable privacy. Unfortunately it seems like you cannot set the "End Screen" option as Thumbnail by default for new uploads or turn off Likes, Watch Later either. Therefore I need to edit these in bulk via Google Sheets, which has a handy "Open Links" which enables you to highlight and open links in multiple tabs.

How can I get the "base" Vimeo url from a private Vimeo Pro video URL?

So this would be

**https://vimeo.com/400532154/**

from the private URL, which is

https://vimeo.com/400532154/b0fedc9dc3

I have tried the following as well as plenty of other formulas from Google but with no joy.

`=LEFT(A2, LEN(A2) - FIND("/", A2))`

Here is the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfMutSvj3bPJMmYf_2igOxePT1EYDrQ8yeuEkIcu888/edit?usp=sharing), you can Make a copy with File-Make a Copy

Comment: It's roundabout, but FWIW you can create an "embed preset" with your desired End Screen, and then apply that embed preset as the default for your videos. Check out the Settings pages here: https://vimeo.com/settings/videos/embed_presets and https://vimeo.com/settings/videos/upload_defaults

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(.+)/")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Did not know that `REGEXTRACT` returns a range of all the catching groups if there are grouping in the pattern. So cool!

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `REGEXEXTRACT` to extract the part of the URL that starts with `https://vimeo.com` or `http://vimeo.com` and the subsequent subpart:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A24, "(?i)^https?://vimeo\.com/[^/]+")
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XKIPhV/2).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `^` - start of string
- `https?://` - `https://` or `http://`
- `vimeo\.com/` - a `vimeo.com/` substring
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "[^/]+$", "")
```

[image]